# How does Python decide wherever to call __setitem__ or __getitem__ methods?

Tags: python

As a C++ programmer, I am looking at the things from position of C++ language. If I want to define an indexing operator, I do it like this:

```
struct S
{
    auto operator [](int) -> string
    {
        throw 0;
        return "hello";
    }
};
```

Notice that my method always throws no matter if it is used for assigning or reading:

```
S s{};
auto v = s[0]; // throws
s[1] = 127; // throws
```

And I was surprised when a similar Python code works differently depending on context:

```
dict = {}
a = dict[0] # throws
dict[1] = 127 # works fine
```

I have found that the indexing operator in Python is syntactic sugar for methods `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`. But how does the interpreter decide which one to call?

Comment: @nikitablack this is just a language feature surely. The Python parser knows if the index is on the left hand side of an assignment and so Python can generate the right code.

Comment: ah true, mixed that up with `at`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of the subscript operator of e..g  [C++ strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) you notice that it returns a reference which is then updated by the assignment.

Since Python cannot (de-)reference everything like C++ it needs to update the value inside the object. That's also why `__setitem__` has an additional parameter for the value to be set that's not necessary in C++.

P.S. sorry you had originally asked:

> But how does the interpreter decide which one to call?

and it was answered in the comments/other answers. The distinction is entirely syntactic: an index operator on the left side of an assignment is interpreted as `__setitem__` and within an expression it is interpreted as `__getitem__`.

Answer (score 3):

> But how does the interpreter decide which one to call?

In C++ parlance, that would be easy to explain: If the result of the operator is an lvalue, call `__setitem__`, otherwise `__getitem__`.

Python doesn't use that lingo, but essentially, if the result is on the left of the assignment operator `=`, `__setitem__` is called (and your AST inherently contains that information).

Comment: Well, this analogy does not work well - in Python, every object is a reference, i.e. a named object, so every returned value should be an lvalue in C++ terms. Now I think that the presence of `=` on the right side is what makes the difference.